# Domino tiling on a cube

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

> The surface of the 9 × 9 × 9 cube is covered completely with 1 × 2 pieces of paper. Some of those pieces cover two squares on the same face, but some
>   bend along cube’s edge. Prove that the number of bending pieces is odd.

This seems pretty similar to a regular 2d case, so let's make every square either white or black, however this wouldn't work at a corner, so I have no idea how to tile. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd rather tile the "small cubes".

There are $9 \times 9 \times 9$ small cubes, each of size $1 \times 1\times 1$. Paint them black and white, alternately, so that all $8$ corners are painted black.

Now notice that a bending piece covers two squares of the same color, while a non-bending piece covers two squares of different colors.

It only remains to calculate the number of black and white squares. This is the same on each face, which is $41$ black and $40$ white. Therefore in total there are $6$ more black squares than white squares.

Let $a$ (resp. $b$) be the number of bending pieces covering two black (resp. white) squares. Then $2a - 2b$ is the difference between black and white squares, which is $6$.

So $a - b = 3$ is odd, hence $a + b$ is also odd.